# Dynamic 2-state toggle button difficulty returning to original state

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, conditional, button, user-interface

I had this working fine this morning, but I proceeded to refactor, and somehow I cannot get it to toggle like before. It does initialize, and it does go from state-1 to state-2 but not back to state-1. That's what I cannot figure out. If you have any suggestions, please help.

```
ClearAll[autosave];
 
Options[autosave] = {"ButtonOptions" -> {}};
autosave[bgs_ : {Darker@Blue, Darker@Green}, cols_ : {White, White}, 
   labs_ : {"AutoSave", "Saving"}, size_ : {75, 25}, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{
    state := CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave],
    flip := 
     SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
      NotebookAutoSave -> If[TrueQ[state], False, True]]
    },
   toggle[flp_ : True] := CompoundExpression[
     If[TrueQ[flp], flip],
     Echo@{flp, state};
     col = If[TrueQ[state], Last[cols], First[cols]],
     label = If[TrueQ[state], Last[labs], First[labs]],
     bg = If[TrueQ[state], Last[bgs], First[bgs]]];
   Dynamic[
    Button[label, toggle[], BaseStyle -> col, 
     Background -> Dynamic[bg], ImageSize -> size, 
     Apply[Sequence, OptionValue["ButtonOptions"]]], 
    Initialization :> toggle[False]]];

autosave[]
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave] = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to reset the variable "state":

```
autosave[bgs_ : {Darker@Blue, Darker@Green}, cols_ : {White, White}, 
   labs_ : {"AutoSave", "Saving"}, size_ : {75, 25}, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{state := 
     CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave], 
    flip := SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
      NotebookAutoSave -> (state = If[TrueQ[state], False, True])]}, 
   toggle[flp_ : True] := 
    CompoundExpression[If[TrueQ[flp], flip], Echo@{flp, state};
     col = If[TrueQ[state], Last[cols], First[cols]], 
     label = If[TrueQ[state], Last[labs], First[labs]], 
     bg = If[TrueQ[state], Last[bgs], First[bgs]]];
   Dynamic[
    Button[label, toggle[], BaseStyle -> col, 
     Background -> Dynamic[bg], ImageSize -> size, 
     Apply[Sequence, OptionValue["ButtonOptions"]]], 
    Initialization :> toggle[False]]];
```

Comment: this is maybe the 5th or 6th you came through for me. thank you so much! just one question. why did `state:=CurrentValue[...]` need to be reset if its definition uses `SetDelay` so that it acts like a regular function always performing its instructions fresh each time it's called?

Comment: state simply reads the current value but does not toggle it.

Comment: yes i know. that's why I have `flip` and `toggle` functions. here is the definition from my post: `state := CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave]`. funny thing is it worked when i used it every time i needed a property (i toggle up to 4 of them and 1 more for `flip`) and I thought that was very inefficient so i refactored it to only call `state` twice instead of 5 times.